# A strange lesson from a bilingual American. About article "the"

Tags: definite-article, pronunciation

I just have happened to have found [**this video.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIVso2e7QTk)

He is teaching English in Japanese TV and is saying he is frustrated about every time he speaks the as in "thə" (which should grammatically be pronounced before the consonant) even the vowel comes after it, TV staff "corrects" it (according to him, the staff are not native speakers but it is not important according to him.)

What surprised me is he is saying "there is no such a rule."

Please listen from 3:01～

> While not immediately apparent, one of the most important reasons for studying the history is that THE(thə) events of the past and the activities...

He insists furthermore.

From 4:16～,

He pronounces the before the vowel word **idea** as in thə, not in thē.

He says from 2:03

> No, No, I'm pretty sure you can say either one now.

What baffled me is, he says, from 1:48

> Nobody follows that rule anymore

I'm completely dumbfounded.

Is his claim acceptable to the "true" native speakers?
(Kindly forget when they are speaking only in Japanese.)

Comment: That Nick guy is cheating. He is reading from a book at a slow enough pace that he has time to think about how he "should" pronounce the definite article "the" as he is doing it. And I disagree with him. You need to listen to how real people talk in real life. Here is [an example](https://youtu.be/9axG7EhGNmI?t=539).

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks! The black guy in the link never says thə but thē before the vowels. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. My link should take you to a point in a video where the girl says "sing in _the_ idea" with a long vowel [iː/ē]. To be more precise, yes, occasionally native speakers do pronounce the definite article before a vowel with a schwa [ə], but that is not common and should not be used to refute the vowel/consonant convention.